# Large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

Tags: c++, gcc

```
    const DWORD exp_table_common[PLAYER_EXP_TABLE_MAX + 1] = {
        9000000000ULL,
    };
extern const DWORD exp_table_common[PLAYER_EXP_TABLE_MAX + 1];
```

When I compile I get this warning:

```
warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
```

And main program read just  400000000 value.

What i can do solve that warning?

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: What i can do solve that warning?

Comment: I tried to change to unsigned int same thing

Comment: The question belongs into, well, the question, not a comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious choice is to use

```
const unsigned long long table_common[...] = { 9000000000ULL };
```

Note, that only the first element of `table_common` gets initialized with `9000000000ULL`. All other elements get initialized with `0ull`.

Comment: Thanks, best answer. :) Now i understand.